# Central-Slice-Theorem Analogue for Wavelet Transforms?

Tags: integral-transforms

The 2D Radon transform and the 2D Fourier transform are related by the so-called Central Slice Theorem (cf e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-slice_theorem) and I would like to know, whether there is an analogous theorem for the 2D Wavelet transform and, if there is, what is the transform that is the analogue of the Radon transform in that case.

Comment: Why do you think that such analog should exist? The 2D Fourier transform and the 2D wavelet transform are not really similar things. You are aware of the fact that the wavelet transform results in a function that lives on a different set, right? Meanwhile, you may be interested in the ridgelet transform which combines the Radon and the wavelet transform.